# Using where condition with scalar functions vs where condition using cross apply & table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to determine the best approach (fastest!) for a stored procedure I am creating. It's a fairly basic stored procedure that will be used to compare fields between two systems for data integrity. At first I though about using temp tables and adding indexes, but I did not see any difference in speed. Then upon reading about performance gains via table valued functions I figured that would be a way to go, but some simple testing isn't showing any improvements. The reason I was even concerned about optimizing my query is because the where condition will use many scalar functions, due to mismatching field lengths between systems (a whole other issue), so I assumed doing many scalar functions within a where clause would be bad for performance.

Here is approach #1:

```
SELECT
SLXID
FROM dbo.Salesforce_Contacts a WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN _SLX_Contact b WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON a.SLXID = b.Contactid
WHERE
a.IsDeleted = 0
AND
(
LEFT(a.FirstName, 32) != b.FirstName
AND LEFT(a.LastName, 32) != b.LastName
AND LEFT(a.Title, 64) != b.Title
AND dbo.GetSLXContactStatus(a.Contact_Status__c) != b.Status
)
```

And here is approach #2 using table valued function:

```
SELECT
a.SLXID
FROM dbo.Salesforce_Contacts a WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN _SLX_Contact b WITH(NOLOCK)
ON a.SLXID = b.Contactid
CROSS APPLY
dbo._SFContact_Functions_TEMP(a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Title, a.Contact_Status__c)  CA
WHERE 
a.IsDeleted = 0
AND
(
b.FirstName != CA.FirstName_32
AND b.LastName != CA.LastName_32 -- etc.
AND b.Title != CA.Title_64
AND b.Status != CA.Contact_Status
)
```

Here is the Table Valued Function used in #2:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo._SFContact_Functions_TEMP 
( 
 @FirstName VARCHAR(40) 
,@LastName VARCHAR(80)
,@Title VARCHAR(128)
,@Status VARCHAR(20)
)

RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN

SELECT 
 LEFT(@FirstName, 32) FirstName_32
,LEFT(@LastName, 32) LastName_32
,LEFT(@Title, 64) Title_64
,dbo.GetSLXContactStatus(@Status) Contact_Status
GO
```

And finally here are the execution plans (actual):

For #1
[image: #1]
For #2
[image: #2]
Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I prefer the version without the user-defined function; it just seems simpler.  But what is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm being ocd most likely. The query takes 20-40 seconds to finish, which is unusually long (relatively), so I'd like to speed it up of possible. Maybe the left functions, etc. and the time it takes is just unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

1st approach is better .

In first place,what you are trying to do ?Database design seem to be wrong.

is this one time query or permanent.

Assuming that what u are trying to do is correct,then 20-40 second is far less time.

Also show what is inside dbo.GetSLXContactStatus(a.Contact_Status__c).

May be once try like this,

```
tABLE dbo.Salesforce_Contacts
cLUSTERED INDEX ON SLXID
Create non clusterindex on IsDeleted AND INCLUDE COLUMN(FirstName,LastName,Title)

tABLE dbo._SLX_Contact
cLUSTERED INDEX ON Contactid

;With CTE
(
 SELECT SLXID ,LEFT(a.FirstName, 32) FirstName, LEFT(a.LastName, 32) LastName
, LEFT(a.Title, 64) Title
FROM dbo.Salesforce_Contacts a WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE
a.IsDeleted = 0

)

select * from CTE
JOIN _SLX_Contact b WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON a.SLXID = b.Contactid
WHERE 
a.FirstName=! b.FirstName
 AND (a.LastName != b.LastName
AND a.Title != b.Title
AND dbo.GetSLXContactStatus(a.Contact_Status__c) != b.Status-- EXPLAIN THIS
)
```

IF YOU HAVE LOT OF RECORDS THEN MAY YOU CAN INSERT CTE RECORD IN TEMP TABLE WITH PROPER INDEX

Answer (score 0):

From the picture provided there is little or no difference in performance and automatically optimized plans #1 and #2. SSMS hints you an extra index. Analyze #1 and #2 if they are different (hardly possible). Try to add indexes offered. Analyze what exactly is used by the plans.